# How can I import my data.frame as an igraph object?

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to use the igraph library. I have a data.frame with 3 columns which looks like this :

```
> head(data)
     var1    var2  corr
1 OTU0001 OTU0004 0.804
2 OTU0001 OTU0014 0.644
3 OTU0004 OTU0014 0.664
4 OTU0001 OTU0016 0.730
5 OTU0004 OTU0016 0.674
6 OTU0014 OTU0016 0.655
```

Is it possible to import it ?

Comment: What is the meaning of `var1`, `var2`, and `corr` in the context of graphs? From/to vertices and weights?

Comment: Actually, this a pairwise correlation dataframe. `corr` is the correlation between my differents variables

Answer (score 2):

Check out the manual: https://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph.pdf

You could use something like:

```
library(igraph)

data <- data.frame(var1=c("OUT0001","OUT0001","OUT0004","OUT0001","OUT0004","OUT0014"),
                   var2=c("OUT0004","OUT0014","OUT0014","OUT0016","OUT0016","OUT0016"),
                   corr=c(0.804,0.644,0.664,0.730,0.674,0.655))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(data, directed=TRUE)
plot(g)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I've got another question : my data.frame has thousands of rows, even when I filter the last column, with `corr>0.8` . Does it make sense to make a network with a huge number of rows?